# Why do so many popular Helm charts have low security ratings? Does it matter?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I'm still learning Kubernetes and Helm. Today I went to [ArtifactHub](https://artifacthub.io/packages/search), and it looks like a lot of popular Helm charts have low security ratings (D or F). For example, [PostgreSQL](https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/bitnami/postgresql), [Redis](https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/bitnami/redis), [Elasticsearch](https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/elastic/elasticsearch).

Why do so many popular Helm packages have low security ratings? Does it matter? Should I not use a Helm chart if it has a low security rating?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Those security ratings are mostly based on the vulnerabilities which are present in the base images. For example, if application docker image is build on top of the base image which has poor ratings (lots of outdated packages, libraries), its rating is going to be low as well. In general I would not care so much about those ratings especially if the application does not rely on the base image libraries. What's more, in order to take advantage of those vulnerabilities, one would have to somehow invoke shell from within application, which is a much bigger issue than having vulnerable libraries in your docker image.